# findstr: Gives more matches than expected

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I don't understand why `findstr` doesn't work as I want.

I have the following files in my test directory:

```
aaa.jpg
bbb.png
ccc.svg

aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.png
ccc_s.svg

aaa_small.jpg
bbb_small.png
ccc_small.svg
```

And I have the following line to pass directly to cmd.exe:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /a:-d ^| findstr /ile "gif jpg png svg" ^| findstr /ie "_s.*"') do echo "%f"
```

To my opinion, it should match the following files:

```
aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.png
ccc_s.svg
```

However, it's actually matches

```
aaa_s.jpg
bbb_s.png
ccc_s.svg

aaa_small.jpg
bbb_small.png
ccc_small.svg
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is a `FindStr` wildcard for any character, and `*` is for zero or more occurrences of the previous character. So obviously `_s.*` matches `_s` followed by any character zero or more times; which covers `_sm`.

Please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, press the 'enter' key, and read the usage information.

BTW, what's wrong with using:

```batch-file
Dir /B /A:-D *_s.*
```

If needs be you could pipe that to `FindStr` with `/I /L /E ".gif .jpg .png .svg"` for example:

```batch-file
Dir /B /A:-D *_s.* | FindStr /I /L /E ".gif .jpg .png .svg"
```

Alternatively you could include multiple matches to your `Dir` command and forget about using `FindStr` entirely:

```batch-file
Dir /B /A:-D "*_s.gif" "*_s.jpg" "*_s.png" "*_s.svg"
```

Comment: Is there a way to simply escape the dot? I tried to replace it with `\.`, but it doesn't work

Comment: @johnc.j., which dot, _(period)_, in which of my examples, requires escaping, and is failing to do so? _Please do not inform me about a scenario, which is outside of the scope of the question at the time of my answering, or my examples, because that would obviously be a different question._

Comment: I talk about the period in my original code, here: `findstr /ie "_s.*"`. I tried to change it to `findstr /ie "_s\.*"`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @johnc.j., that's because you've asked it to match any string which case insensitively `E`nds with `_s.` followed by zero or more periods, and none of your files end with periods, they all end with `f` or `g`!